# opening Sublime text from Git Bash but getting comamand not found

Tags: bash, git-bash

i messed up a little bit in my GIt Bash, I added an alias and can't get rid of it. whenever l launce Git Bash I get this error right away:
[`bash: alias: alias: not found`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnnqp.png)

and when I'm trying to run subl I am getting this error message:
[`bash: C:Program: command not found`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLdVc.png)

even though it is added in my environment variables, however, I am able to open it in CMD. could be the alias is causing the issue? if that's the case how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you share your .bashrc and alias file if you have one?

Comment: mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~
$ alias
alias gpuom='git push origin master'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'
alias node='winpty node.exe'
alias subl='C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'

mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~
$

Comment: bashrc
mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~
$ bashrc
bash: bashrc: command not found

mekstein@FPS104 MINGW64 ~
$

Comment: You're using bash aliases (which is fine), but you have Windows paths in them (which is ... less than fine). Your bash aliases are probably defined in your `.bashrc` file: note the leading dot, DOT-bash-R-C, not bash-R-C. Note also that git-bash is merely a port *of* bash to Windows, included with Git-for-Windows because Git needs a POSIX-compatible shell, and bash is such a shell and git-bash was there.

Comment: Other than directing you to the wrong file, [nbstrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324115/1256452) is fine here: you want to set up your aliases with forward slashes, and quoted white-space, because bash—which is from the Unix/Linux world—doesn't believe that calling a directory "Program Files (x86)" is sensible and it will break up arguments at white space even if those are parts of the path, unless you quote the spaces.

Comment: Don't include screenshots of text in questions -- copy-and-paste the textual transcript directly into your question, and put it in a code-formatted section. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please edit your `.bashrc` **into the question itself**, using the [edit] button. Adding it as a comment means we don't have the whitespace, line endings, etc.

Comment: BTW, you don't run `bashrc` as a command to see your .bashrc contents -- it's a configuration file in your home directory; you open it with a text editor, or display it with tools like `cat` or `less`. `ls -a ~/` shows all the files in your home directory, including hidden ones; if there's a `.bashrc` there, then `cat ~/.bashrc` will show its contents.

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like you have the alias path defined incorrectly.

Your alias for subl also looks like it is using a Windows path. The examples below are from my dev machine for my GitExtension and Powershell aliases on a Windows machine.

Take note how it is using a unix style path wrapped in single quotes and without a space between the equal sign and the first single quote mark.

```
alias ps='"/c/windows/system32/windowspowershell/v1.0/powershell.exe"'

alias gite='"/c/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe"'
```

Comment out the alias that you are having problems with to troubleshoot this alias issue. The aliases are typically defined in the .gitconfig file. Mine is located at c:\Users\nbstrat\.gitconfig.

---

From the path you specified in the comments above, updated your subl alias path to this:

```
alias subl='"/C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'
```

Close your current git bash shell and then restart git bash so it will reload the updated aliases.

Comment: is there a way to remove the alias?

Comment: Yes - Aliases are typically stored in the ~/. gitconfig or path/to/project/. git/config files. My dev machines use .dot file configurations so all the aliases are defined in a separate .alias file so I don't have one that I can look at at the moment to give you the actual path.

Comment: so how can i fix my above issue?

Comment: it should be in C:/program files/Git/etc/...   no?
why can't i find it there?

Comment: The .gitconfig file is typically created within your profile directory c:\Users\<your name>\.gitconfig

Comment: Soory for bothering,
this is what i see when i open the config file

Comment: [filter "lfs"]
 clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
 smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
 process = git-lfs filter-process
 required = true
[user]
 name = MOshea
 email = arye6700@gmail.com

Comment: it may be in your local config - look in <git-repo>\.git\config.  In the event it is in the local config, I would move the aliases to the global config so that the alias would be the same regardless of which git repository I am currently using.

Comment: Note that there is a difference (a fairly large one) between a *Git* alias and a *bash* alias. A Git alias is invoked when you run `git xyz` and `xyz` is a Git alias. A bash alias is invoked when you run `xyz` (note: no "git" part) and `xyz` is a bash alias. Bash aliases are defined in, and by, bash. Git aliases are defined in, and by, Git. The two don't behave the same.

Comment: Aliases defined in bash, with `alias <cmd>=<expansion>`, are bash aliases. So these are all bash aliases: none of your examples here are Git aliases. That's fine as the OP's issue is with a bash alias. But he should not be looking in `.gitconfig` files as those store *Git* aliases (and many other Git settings).